# Slow bufferring from PHP to windows commandline

Tags: php, cmd, xampp, buffer, output

One of my Sanskrit related code has many echo statements in it which are triggered as and when some condition is satisfied.
Recently I wanted to write the output to file also rather than only to browser.
So, I was suggested to go for ob_start() and fputs($outfile,ob_get_contents()).
I tried this with my code.

```
ob_start();
// Some 100 KB echo statements here.
fputs($outfile,ob_get_contents());
ob_end_flush();
```

The code works perfectly fine for small data sizes in both browser testing in localhost on XAMPP, and windows cmd commandline.

But, as the code has some 100 kb data to be shown, the process time varies a lot.
In XAMPP localhost testing it took me 1:05 mins to execute the whole code.
And in windows cmd it took me around 10 mins to execute 1/6th of the code. (I couldn't bear till it ends).

I guess there is something with the data size which CMD can handle and I am pumping too much of data to it.
Is there something which I can do to fix this problem ?
I want my commandline to work faster.

this output buffer is not mandatory. 
All I want to achieve is to echo as well as write it to some file.

Comment: ob has some overhead to it. but it shouldn't explode your execution times like that.

Comment: But it does. Thats the strange item

Comment: could be a linux/windows difference. no idea what all gets hacked up inside PHP to make it run on windows.

Comment: Let me try it on cygwin if I can overcome this issue

Comment: no luck with cygwin terminal (linux kind) too. It also is similarly slow. In both the code moves forward - but very slow.

Comment: cygwin's generally pretty slow anyways, since it has to dynamically translate unixisms<->windowisms. have you tried modifying your code so it DOESN'T do all those echoes, and does string building instead? e.g. `echo 'a'; echo 'b'` -> `$text = 'a'; $text .= 'b'; echo $text`?

Comment: tried building the string. Still the same problem. Browser execution takes 1 min and commandline more than an hour

Comment: then start putting in timing statements and see where the slowdown is. string building would be the same no matter what platform you're on, so the slowdown must be elsewhere.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP output buffer too slow in windows commandline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732810/php-output-buffer-too-slow-in-windows-commandline)

Comment: You already asked this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732810/php-output-buffer-too-slow-in-windows-commandline) before. Please read [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers)